# weird html textarea bug

Tags: javascript, html

I have this weird HTML text area bug, where I click on the textarea, to type something the position of the white background changes, quickly, then moves back and stays there.

I have tried both in chrome and firefox, and it appears in both places. I tried disabling all javascript on my page, but the error still appears.

I have not added anything specific CSS, apart from google fonts, but that didn't seem to be the problem either.

[image: Here is a picture of the error, when it happens.]

I don't think anything in my code, seems to be the problem, but here it is:

```
<h1 class="mb-5"> Enter your message, and i will get back to you as soon as possible</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('send_mail') }}" method="post">
    First name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" size="35"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" size="35"><br>
    Email-address: <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" size="35"><br>
    Phone-number: <br>
    <input type="text" name="phone" size="35"><br>
    Enter your message: <br>
    <br>
    <textarea type="text" name="message" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea><br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" >Let's get in touch</a>
</form>
```

NOTE:

I'm using flask for my application, but the problem appears, both when I run from flask, and when I run as a static HTML page.

Comment: Can you show the CSS? It's hard to figure out how to solve a problem without being able to reproduce it. You can use the code button in the editor to create a demo of the problem

Comment: It's Grammarly, it does that to all TextAreas when it loads on the page. Very annoying but not and issue with your code. Try deactivating it and see if it still happens.

Comment: Hey, could you try to replicate the error in https://jsfiddle.net/ or something like that

Comment: @kristheman Glad i could help.

Comment: @moplin it was a problem with an extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that might help you.

You might want to use a fresh instance of chrome when debugin. This will keep buggy extensions from giving you a headache.
Try the following:

> To guarantee a clean profile doesn't inherit any extensions or settings, launch Chrome using the --user-data-dir switch with the path '/dev/null'. e.g:

```
▪   OSX: open -a "Google Chrome" --args --user-data-dir=/dev/null
▪   Linux: google-chrome --user-data-dir=/dev/null
▪   Windows: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=/dev/null
```

> Launching Chrome like this will ensure you get a completely empty profile instead of loading the user's profile as read-only.

Ref:  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/clean-testing-environment